# Creating custom Community Template

Tags: community, lightning-community, template, lightning-bolt

Is it necessary to use the templates (Kokua, KOA, Napili) provided by salesforce for building community or we can create our own community templates?

If yes, how is it possible. i am unable to find sufficient references over for generating new community templates other than provided ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

Quote from the Set Up and Manage Salesforce Communities - communities.pdf (first link below)

> Community Builder makes it super easy to customize your community. Simply edit a few components to include information about your community, add images to extend your branding, and you’re ready to go—without any coding! Also, if you want a more custom experience, you can create custom pages, add components to pages, use custom Lightning components, and expose more
>   Salesforce objects.

It is possible to use one of the standard templates and build your own pages to use in that community that way you can make a completely custom community, you can also use CSS to adapt the look and feel of the community. More information can be found here:

https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/208/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/communities.pdf

https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/208/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/community_templates.pdf

Hope it helps. 
Best regards, 
Christian.

Answer (score 2):

Kokua and Koa are no longer offered.

[image]

From the Napili template, you can customize the appearance and functionality quite easily. You also have access to Salesforce Tabs + Visualforce.

Depending on your use case, you can chose from either one, as mentioned earlier both are "Easily" customizable if you know what you are doing.

The way to go for customizing your Lightning community is to [Create a Custom Theme Layout Component for Communities](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_builder_theme_layout.htm)

Additionally, you have several branding options to customize the look and feel of the community:

[image]

As you can see, next to Branding, you can add CSS rules to customize the whole of your community,and the settings allow you to further add customizations through Theme, Advanced, and so on:

[image]

Comment: This has been the approach that I have recently been using, it is pretty effective as you really can make the community look different using the inbuilt components plus the Theme.